# Use variable from function that takes argument in another function

Tags: python

So I'm making this Weather app since API for weather data takes only latitude and longitude (afaik) I'm using another API to get them by city name. So `GetGeo` takes city name and returns latitude and longitude which then I need to use in GetWeather function the problem is I don't know how to make them accessible in this function, the only way I found is lat, `lon = GetGeo()` but this isn't working since GetGeo is taking argument which I pass in from input field. I understand that this probably isn't the best way to do this but I'm a beginner and I already made this work without having separate functions, but I like to challenge myself and want to separate everything in functions :)

```
def GetGeo(cityName):
    locationKey = 'xxx'
    locationUrl = "https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/search.php?key=" + locationKey + '&q=' + cityName + '&format=json'
    locationDataReq = requests.get(locationUrl)
    locationData = locationDataReq.json()
    lat = locationData[0]['lat']
    lon = locationData[0]['lon']

    return lat, lon

def GetWeather():
    lat, lon = GetGeo()
    darkSkyKey = 'xxx'
    darkSkyUrl = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + darkSkyKey + "/" + lat + "," + lon + "?units=si"
    darkSkyDataReq = requests.get(darkSkyUrl)
    darkSkyData = darkSkyDataReq.json()
    label["text"] = darkSkyData
    print(darkSkyData)
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem of not being able to pass input to getgeo in getweather function? I did not understand.

Comment: input gets passed to getgeo successfully the problem is i need to  use latitude and longitude from getgeo in get weather, and I dont know how to use those variables from GetGeo in GetWeather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```py
def GetGeo(cityName):
    locationKey = 'xxx'
    locationUrl = "https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/search.php?key=" + locationKey + '&q=' + cityName + '&format=json'
    locationDataReq = requests.get(locationUrl)
    locationData = locationDataReq.json()
    lat = locationData[0]['lat']
    lon = locationData[0]['lon']

    return lat, lon

def GetWeather(cityName):
    lat, lon = GetGeo(cityName)
    darkSkyKey = 'xxx'
    darkSkyUrl = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + darkSkyKey + "/" + lat + "," + lon + "?units=si"
    darkSkyDataReq = requests.get(darkSkyUrl)
    darkSkyData = darkSkyDataReq.json()
    label["text"] = darkSkyData
    print(darkSkyData)


qCity=input('please type city: ')
GetWeather(qCity)
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly the edit that I was thinking of but assuming that was already tried.

Comment: Doesnt work as I dont need cityName to be in GetWeather. GetWeather shouldnt take any arguments, it needs to take returned values from GetGeo only

Comment: Thanks actually it worked. I was starting GetGeo function first instead of GetWeather.